# Can "cess" mean either "go, move" and "cease"?

Tags: etymology

In "incessant", "cess" mean "cease", while in "secession", "cess" mean "go, move"

So can "cess" mean either "go, move" and "cease", two  meanings contradictory to each other?

Comment: What did etymonline say? You should try to look these up first before asking here.

Comment: @Mitch: I have put what I saw from etymonline in my post, although I didn't mention "etymonline" explicitly.

Comment: If you put that in your post, you should make it explicit. Otherwise, it reads like you've already answered your title question (the answer is a feeble 'yes').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Cess-* is the supine stem of Latin **cedo**, "to go, give way". Words on *-io(n)* are generally derived directly from the supine stem of a verb, so *se-cession* means "going away and apart from somewhere", with the prefix *se-* meaning "apart".

A desiderative or frequentative verb **cesso** was also formed from this supine stem, meaning "try to get away, stand back, be remiss, cease". *incessant* must have been based on this verb, because *-nt* is not used with a supine stem except when a new verb has been created as an intermediate step. The prefix *in-* means "un-", so *incessant* means "unceasing".

So the change in meaning between *secession* and *incessant* happened in the development of the meaning of the verb *cesso*, from which *incessant* is derived, but not *secession*, which is derived directly from *cedo*.

Comment: Is that development of meaning in Latin or in English?

Comment: @Mitch: It is the development of English words in the history of English, which also includes the Latin phase, as you well know. You will find similar etymologies all over the Oxford **English** Dictionary, too; but the ones for these words don't treat the Latin phase as extensively as needed, as opposed to, e.g., the article on *-ine*. An arbitrary limitation of disciplines is bad for arts and sciences alike. Edit: in case that was a genuine question, I take it all back and replace it with "Latin".

Comment: My question was sincere. Was the meaning change that you refer to during Classical Latin, or was it when those words were first used as neologisms in English in the 15th-16th c. or in the past 5 centuries of English usage?

Comment: @Mitch: Oh, then  I apologise. The change occurred in Antiquity.